# Exception while converting dates

Tags: java, jpa, jooq

I have the following table structure where some of the columns are timestamps:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_space` (
  `ps_date_created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ps_date_modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  //some other fields
)
```

I also have a domain class which represents a row in the table and includes all of these date fields as `ZonedDateTime`:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ProductSpace {

    @Column(name = CREATED_AT)
    private ZonedDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = UPDATED_AT)
    private ZonedDateTime updatedAt;

    @Column(name = PS_DATE_CREATED)
    private ZonedDateTime psDateCreated;

    @Column(name = PS_DATE_MODIFIED)
    private ZonedDateTime psDateModified;

    //some other fields
}
```

And then I'm trying to run the following query:

```
Optional.ofNullable(
    DSL.using(configuration)
        .selectFrom(PRODUCT_SPACE_TABLE_NAME)
        .where(field(GTIN, Long.class).eq(gtin))
        .fetchAny())
    .map(x -> x.into(ProductSpace.class));
```

Which produces an exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from 1 (class org.jooq.types.ULong) to class java.time.ZonedDateTime
```

I need to keep domain as it is and do not change field types, so need to keep ZonedDateTime. However, have no idea of how to resolve the issue.

Would really appreciate any help with regards to this.

Comment: which version used?

Comment: @JacekCz 3.10.4

Comment: what JPA provider and what version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ doesn't support the `ZonedDateTime` type as there is no specification in JDBC on how to map it to the underlying SQL data types. You'll have to map the type yourself, manually:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(DSL.using(configuration)
    .selectFrom(PRODUCT_SPACE_TABLE_NAME)
    .where(field(GTIN, Long.class).eq(gtin))
    .fetchAny()
).map(x -> {
    ProductSpace result = new ProductSpace();
    result.setCreatedAt(myConversionFunction(x.get(PRODUCT_SPACE_TABLE_NAME.CREATED_AT)))
    ...
    return result;
});
```

Or, you can extract the above `RecordMapper` lambda into a reusable `RecordMapper`, or you can define your own `RecordMapperProvider`, which overrides the default and implements this type of mapping globally:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider